# Regex.Match() vs new Regex().Match() is there a difference?

Tags: c#, regex

Specifically to memory here, would `Regex.Match()` and `new Regex().Match()` have a difference?

Would not creating a new assertion of the Regex class cost more memory then using `Regex.Match`?

The reason I am asking is I've always been doing `new Regex("pattern").Match("Input")` and saw Regex.Match and I'm now questioning if I'm doing it wrong!

Comment: `Regex.Match` will still use `new Regex()` inside, so from that point there is no difference

Comment: Using a static method should be quicker inside a loop since it uses cached regex. [*To improve performance, the regular expression engine maintains an application-wide cache of compiled regular expressions. The cache stores regular expression patterns that are used only in static method calls. (Regular expression patterns supplied to instance methods are not cached.) This avoids the need to reparse an expression into high-level byte code each time it is used.*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/compilation-and-reuse-in-regular-expressions).

Comment: If you are not constantly recreating a Regex object inside a loop, if you initialize it before, then both methods should work similarly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With that exact syntax, for you as the developer, there is no difference.
except that `new Regex()` is not a public constructor, you have to pass a pattern.

So in that case the Static probably better.

Where you would you `new Regex()` is, to assign it to an instance of a Regex like:

```
var myregex = new Regex("my pattern");
```

You can then check things on the instance like timeout `MatchTimeout` and `Options`.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. The static method Regex.Match is good for situations when you won't need to reuse a Regex object. If you were going to be matching multiple inputs, you would likely want to use

```
Regex reggy = new Regex("pattern");
```

And then use that object as many times as you need it.

Comment: I wish I could give you mark as answer too, your answer was helpful but unfortunately the other user did give a bit more information, but thanks!